# Variance of average of Bernoulli variables

Tags: variance, binomial-distribution, mean

What is the variance of the average of $n$ Bernoulli distributed random variables $Bernoulli(p)$?

So $\text{Var}\left[\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}\right]$

Comment: Sorry, clarified that a bit

Comment: Wouldn't it be the variance of the binomial distribution?

Comment: Don't think so because the binomial distribution is the sum(xi) without the / N term

Comment: The average of n Bernoulli distributed random variables is a proportion. That proportion is the maximum likelihood estimate of the Bernoulli distribution's probability parameter. The Bernoulli distribution is a special case of the binomial, which has the same parameter, same interpretation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n \sim {\rm Bernoulli}(p)$ are IID, then $S = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim {\rm Binomial}(n,p)$.  Therefore, $${\rm Var}[S/n] = \frac{1}{n^2}\cdot np(1-p) = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}.$$